# context of service is null

Tags: android, service, gps

I wrote a service that give GPS location and in location changed i want to compare location information with values from my shared prefrence and show a toast or alart dialog but shared prefrence and tost dosnt work because the context is null. here is my code and my error.please help me.thanks

```
    public class Broadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent service1=new Intent(context,GPSTracker.class);
        context.startService(service1);
        Log.i("service", "service"); 
    }

}
```

and

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener 
        {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        pref=this.getSharedPreferences("mypref",0);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        pref=this.getSharedPreferences("mypref",0);
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }
    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() 
    {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
            {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } 
            else 
            {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) 
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) 
                {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.i("servise",Boolean.toString(pref.getBoolean("default", false)));
        if(pref.getBoolean("default", false)==true)
        {
            String defaultcity=pref.getString("defaultcity", null);
            double defaultlat=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("defaultlat", null));
            double defaultlng=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("defaultlng", null));
            Geocoder go=new Geocoder(GPSTracker.this);
            try 
            {
                List<Address> address=go.getFromLocation(latitude, latitude, 1);
                if(address.get(0).getAdminArea().equals(defaultcity))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if(latitude==defaultlat && longitude==defaultlng)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String s="Your current location has changed.It's better to change default place of praytimes application.";
                        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String TAG="locationchange";
                        Log.i(TAG,"Locationchanged");
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**My error log**

[image: Here is my error log]

Comment: in which line you get NPE?

Comment: in first line of onLocationChanged.it cant read anything from shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log clearly shows that the error occurs in line 214 of `GPSTracker` in the `GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(...)` method. We can't tell which line that is, but you can, so examine that line, look at the object reference on that line, and work why one of them is null.

Comment: OK well just carry on debugging :-).  My next step would be to put Log.i into `onCreate()` and `onStart()`, to check that they're being called, and to see whether result of `this.getSharedPreferences("mypref",0)` is null or not.

Comment: thanks, when i start this class with an instance from an activity this error occur too.

Comment: I don't know, I've never tried to create a service.  I'd look closely at the documentation and examples.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try codes below for context

```
context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
```

Comment: i've tried your shared preference definition and the log part (getting boolean) in an activity context with no error,i think it's related to your context and you should try changing it.

Comment: i know the problem is context and service is context too but nothing work.